# How do I update npm/ node on ubuntu? I keep getting an error

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, node.js, npm

I ran: npm install npm@latest -g
and got:

```
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.2.2
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.2.2
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"9.5.0","node":"v18.15.0"}
```

Comment: See how you required node 18.17.0 or later, and you have node 18.15.0 ... that's the issue. if ubuntu doesn't offer node later than 18.15.0, then you can get the latest/greatest node from nodesource repo - instructions [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions)